# Delete uploaded image when it's removed from editor

Tags: javascript, laravel, server

I created an editor that added images to posts, have uploaded directly to my server and finally inserted to text editor body like:

```
<img src="http://mydev.io:8000/storage/c6bc9b4b0ae0244058a4181f8e84007d-1.jpg">
```

The issue is how I can remove this image from server when user deleted it from the editor

Comment: The only option I see here is keep a copy of the original content and compare it to the new content. If links are removed, remove the linked image.

Comment: Without seeing more of your editor code, hard to say, but you could listen for an event inside your editor textbox once the editor no longer has an image tag inside it, and delete. I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess you are using a Div with contenteditable?

Comment: Yes I use Div @Squiggs

Comment: Is it possible give more info of your code

Comment: depends on the text body is included html tag or not, try check the text body if not str_contains('c6bc9b4b0ae0244058a4181f8e84007d-1.jpg'), then delete the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated, you need to show more code so people can see the ins and outs of your content editor, but something like this is very rough on what you could do to detect the change event and begin to work out whether an image is there or not.

```
var currentImages = [];

$('body').on('focus', '[contenteditable]', function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    $this.data('before', $this.text());
    return $this;
}).on('blur keyup paste input', '[contenteditable]', function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('before') !== $this.text()) {
        $this.data('before', $this.text());
        $this.trigger('change');
    }
});

$('[contenteditable]').on('change', function(){
     //looks like I changed.
     parseContentEditorAndFindImages( $(this) );

});

function parseContentEditorAndFindImages( $elem ){

     var rawHtml = $elem.text();
     currentImages  = [];
     html = $.parseHTML( rawHtml );
     $.each( html, function( i, el ) {
           //parse html here and detect images

     });
}

<div id="myEditor" contenteditable="true"  /">
```